# Firestore not updating SwiftUI grid without reloading the app

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I followed a tutorial online and seem to have a got a few things working correctly, however I'm trying to auto-update my view based on a order which works but only if I close and reopen the app.

Observer.swift

```
class postsobserver: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [datatype1]()

    init() {
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = true

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.settings = settings

        db.collection("posts").order(by: "likes", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { snap, err in

            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)

                return
            }

            for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                if i.type == .added {
                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let name = i.document.get("name") as! String
                    let image = i.document.get("image") as! String
                    let likes = i.document.get("likes") as! String

                    self.posts.append(datatype1(id: id, name: name, image: image, likes: likes))
                }

                if i.type == .removed {
                    let id = i.document.documentID

                    for j in 0 ..< self.posts.count {
                        if self.posts[j].id == id {
                            self.posts.remove(at: j)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }

                if i.type == .modified {
                    let id = i.document.documentID
                    let likes = i.document.get("likes") as! String

                    for j in 0 ..< self.posts.count {
                        if self.posts[j].id == id {
                            self.posts[j].likes = likes
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Home.swift

```
@ObservedObject var postsobserved = postsobserver()

let columns = [
    GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100)),
]

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack {
            if postsobserved.posts.isEmpty {
                Text("no new posts").fontWeight(.heavy)
            } else {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(postsobserved.posts) { i in

                        postCard(user: i.name, image: i.image, id: i.id, likes: i.likes)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

postCard.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct postCard: View {
    var user = ""
    var image = ""
    var id = ""
    var likes = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(user)
                Spacer()
            }

            AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: image))
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: 100)

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    let like = Int.init(self.likes)!
                    db.collection("posts").document(self.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like + 1)"]) { err in

                        if err != nil {
                            print(err)
                            return
                        }

                        print("updated...")
                    }

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.square")
                        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }

                Button(action: {
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    let like = Int.init(self.likes)!
                    db.collection("posts").document(self.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like - 1)"]) { err in

                        if err != nil {
                            print(err)
                            return
                        }

                        print("updated...")
                    }

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.square")
                        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }

                Spacer()

            }.padding(.top, 8)

            Text("\(likes) Likes")

        }.padding(8)
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I made a mistake somewhere but been trying a few things the last 4 hours I thought it be time to ask for help

Edit:

[image: image of the interface]

When I click the arrows, they seem to update correctly without reloading the app but the `.order(by: "likes", descending: true)` doesn't seem to change the order unless I reload the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `@Published` properties on the main thread.

It looks like `db.collection("posts").order(by: "likes", descending: true).addSnapshotListener` is asynchronous - ie. runs in the background.

Wherever you update your `posts` variable:

```
self.posts.append(datatype1(id: id, name: name, image: image, likes: likes))
```

or

```
self.posts.remove(at: j)
```

etc...

wrap it in `DispatchQueue.main`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.posts.append(datatype1(id: id, name: name, image: image, likes: likes))
}
```

---

You can also wrap all your code in the asynchronous response in `DispatchQueue.main`:

```
db.collection("posts").order(by: "likes", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

It looks like you reload your posts in `init` only. This is why it is correct only at the beginning (when you open the app). If you want to reload them on some action, try the following:

```
class postsobserver: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [datatype1]()
    
    private let settings = FirestoreSettings()
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()

    init() {
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = true
        db.settings = settings

        loadPosts()
    }
    
    // function to reload your posts (in the correct order)
    func loadPosts() {
        db.collection("posts").order(by: "likes", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { snap, err in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then call it from your view whenever you want to load updated posts:

```
postsobserved.loadPosts()
```

Alternatively, instead of reloading posts every time, you can sort them locally:

```
ForEach(postsobserved.posts.sorted(by: { /* condition */ })) {i in ...
```

---

Note: I also recommend you to move your Firebase logic to the ObservableObject.

This button action:

```
Button(action: {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let like = Int(self.likes)!
    db.collection("posts").document(self.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like - 1)"]) { err in

        if err != nil {
            print(err)
            return
        }

        print("updated...")
    }

}) {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.square")
        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
}
```

could be extracted to some function inside your `postsobserver` and called in the `Button` directly:

```
Button(action: {
    postsobserver.updateLikes(...)
}) {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.square")
        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
}
```

Comment: wrapped the code in DispatchQueue.main seems to run without errors but the still doest seem to update the grid, I added postCard.swift incase something I'm doing wrong there

Comment: @zeem Did you check (print, debug) that your asynchronous firebase function returns everything as expected?

Comment: it seems to running correctly, just the scrollview / LazyVGrid seems not to update the order without reloading the app.

Comment: thanks @pawello2222 made the changes, however not sure where to call the postsobserved.loadPosts() I added as a .onAppear statement after the else but think it just looped and got the error "each layout item may only occur once.."

ForEach(postsobserved.posts.sorted(by condition, doesn't seem to like when add "likes" seems to just crash out.

I have a feeling I'm doing something very silly somewhere

Comment: @zeem You probably want to update posts when you click the arrow up/down button. So you can place `postsobserved.loadPosts()` in this button action (after you update likes). Alternatively consider sorting in the ForEach directly. It may be better if you don't want to reload posts every time smth changes.

Comment: thanks  pawello, think I'm almost there but not sure the right condition for the ForEach(postsobserved.posts.sorted(by: { /* condition */ }) when I start that line Xcode gives me:ForEach(postsobserved.posts.sorted(by: <#T##(datatype1, datatype1) throws -> Bool#>))

Comment: @zeem I meant you need to replace `/* condition */` with your own code. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/arrays/how-to-sort-an-array-using-sort

Comment: sometimes all you need a stronger coffee :) thank you so much for all your help @pawello2222

ForEach(postsobserved.posts.sorted(by: { $0.likes > $1.likes })){I in ...

solved it  working as it should now